# How can I trigger a JS Events on HTML using another JS script?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, events

I am trying to reverse engineer a work website to allow me to use a JS script **no jquery** to enter the details for me in a form.

I have saved the HTML on my desktop, pointed all the src files to the right places, now I am creating the script to autofill by using document.getElementById & .click and entering strings into input boxes no problem.

The problem is that there is some kind of Data Validation on one of the boxes in the form of a JS Event, like click, input and Keypress.

This is no problem when I manually type the details in the input boxes no problem, but when JS does this for me it doesn't trigger and doesn't allow me to move on.

Is there another way I can trigger this event without me clicking the input boxes? I can't edit Index.js for reasons.

Input box

```
<input _ngcontent-c4="" class="input-cust-style-orderForm ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" type="text" id="order_id_restrict" placeholder="Enter Reference Number" required="">
```

It has, Click, Keypress, blur, compositionstart & end, ngmodelchange and there are about 4 other input boxes with the same events.

My code has things like:

```
//click the first li in the dropdown list
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]
        .getElementsByTagName("li")[0].click();

var cpName = document.getElementById('cp_name');
    cpName.value = 'something something'
```

Can I trigger events that are already on the website by calling them somehow?

Comment: Maybe you can try with `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()` ([see on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent))

Comment: So something like, cpName.dispatchEvent() ? Do I need to specify an argument like cpName.dispatchEvent(keypress)?

Comment: Yes, you do; `cpName.dispatchEvent('event-name-you-want-to-dispatch')`;